# Does Linux and Mac OSX have built-in Credential/Password Managers with API access?

Tags: password-management, mobile, operating-systems, credentials, desktop

Does Linux and Mac OSX have built-in Credential/Password Managers with API access like Windows has with its CredMan (CredWrite, etc). It would be preferrable if they could be used without the need to have them installed.

Are there ones for Android and IOS?

Is Windows CredMan the best built-in choice to use on Windows XP and later to securely store credentials or even just strings?

Comment: @Off-topic Voters. I don't agree that this post is off-topic because being able to securely store usernames and passwords is all about information security. Unless it is better suited for Stackoverflow. The mention of APIs should not subtract from the security related question. The main question also has definite answers thus being specific and not based on opinion proven by the first answer recieved.

Comment: @Off-topic Voters. to continue... Seeing that stackexchange has a high rating on Google this post might help someone in future who with a simple search might find this post. Something which did not happen to me when I initially searched for an answer to my question. In fact I am still looking for the answer for Linux. Please consider leaving this post as open.

Comment: I think the issue here might be that this too broad and/or a "shopping list" request, I suggest posting a question on https://security.meta.stackexchange.com to get help rewording and reopening

Comment: on GNU/Linux distributions you will typically find `libsecret` already installed, it has GUI interfaces on both GNOME and KDE desktops, libsecret has an API and there are wrapper libraries for several languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apple iOS and Mac OS X have an internal Keychain with Api access, have a look at [Apple Dev doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Comment: Being the only one that answered at least with one OS, I think you deserve the Accepted Answer